# C++ Determine if binary is writable and updatable (it's not running)

Tags: c++, windows

How can I check if a file(binary) is writable and "updatable" (meaning that the binary is not running and I can modify it since in Windows you can't modify a running binary).

Of course I can list the running processes and look it up in there but I would like to use a more direct approach if possible.

How can I distinguish between a fail because I have no write rights or fail because the binary is currently running?

Can [AccessCheck](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374815%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) provide that info?

Thank you

Comment: The simplest way is to just open the file for writing, and see if it fails. Or, in the case of an updater, to just overwrite the file with a new one and see if it fails.  Anything else is a race condition waiting to happen.

Comment: Should it fail in windows if the process is running? How can I distinguish between a fail because I have no write rights or fail because the binary is currently running?

Comment: Yes, it should fail, because (as you stated) Windows locks the file while the process is running.  Use `GetLastError()` to find out why it fails.

Comment: Can I know if the open failed because I have no rights or  because it is running?

Comment: I'm going to try using `GetLastError()` and see if I can differentiate cases. Thanks

Comment: Not *specifically*, as there is no error code for "because the file is running a process", but you might see `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` vs `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`, or similar. Or just enumerate processes until you find one that belongs to the file in question.

Comment: Wow! I just checked and you can delete a running binary in Windows 10. I thought you can't do that.

Comment: @user1618465 You can do that in Linux too. The file isn't really deleted until all open file handles are closed. The details are more nuanced than that, but it's about right.

Comment: @user1618465 Windows also allows you to rename an EXE file while it is running, and then you can copy in a replacement file using the old EXE name.